# What is quicker in nodeJs to process, else if statements or avoiding them with return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, if-statement

What is quicker to process in javascript or NodeJS, `else if` statements or avoiding them with `return`s?

### Case A

```
function test(x) {
  if (x < 2000) {
    return 'output1'
  } else if (x > 3450) {
    return 'output2'
  } else {
    return 'output3'
  }
}
```

### Case B

```
function test(x) {
  if (x < 2000) {
    return 'output1'
  } 
  if (x > 3450) {
    return 'output2'
  } 
  return 'output3'
}
```

I have a gut feeling that case B is quicker with better performance, but just want to confirm with your feedback. Yes, I'm aware the difference is tiny and it would be merely a micro-optimization, but what is faster, case A or B?

Comment: The difference will be so marginal that it's irrelevant…

Comment: Run a benchmark. It's a micro-optimization anyway.

Comment: Maybe run a performance test? But I wouldn't be surprised if the compiled code is completely identical

Comment: There is no need for else after a return

Comment: Also, this can entirely be simplified to `return x !== 798789`…

Comment: @deceze I know `:)` imagine on the last statement is `return 123` instead

Comment: @mplungjan but is that difference merely aesthetic or performance?

Comment: I could actually not care. I would think a tiny performance gain to not parse the else. Reading the code is faster ;)

Comment: @mplungjan that's my point, case A I find it more intuitive to read specially if there's a lot of code before the return, but I was afraid case B is quicker

Comment: This is faster to read assuming new lines between `if (x === 12142) return true;  if (x === 798789) return false; return 'error'` but be careful since "errror" is truthy

Comment: @mplungjan I know any non void string is truthy, but that's not the point `:)` It's hard to pose good questions straight to the point `:)`

Comment: If you want to know what's *faster*: benchmark it on your desired Javascript engine. If you want to know what's more readable: that's opinion based.

Comment: @deceze can you give me a link/reference to such benchmark? I've never heard of it.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/ is one, https://jsben.ch/ another

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira However, [proceed with care](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html)

Comment: @deceze check my answer, thanks for the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An else is always implied when you have an if (because the compiler should know where to jump when the condition is not met. This "where" part is the implied else). There are no scopes in the produced compiled code. There are only instructions one after another. Some of them are labeled so they can be the target of a jump.

I am pretty sure that the output of both code samples is exactly the same. In pseudoassembly it would be something like

```
        [check-equal] $x, 12142  // check equality
        [goto-if-zero] :label1   // Conditional jump to label1 position in case previous check was false
        [set-retval] 'output1'   // setting return value
        [goto] :end              // unconditional jump to the end of funtion
label1: [check-equal] $x, 798789 // check equality 
        [goto-if-zero] :label2   // Conditional jump to label2 position in case previous check was false
        [set-retval] 'output2'   // setting return value
        [goto] end               // unconditional jump to the end of funtion
label2: [setretval] 'output3'    // setting return value
end:    [return]                 // returing
```

Comment: thanks a lot, thus is merely a question of aesthetics

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for citing me the Javascript benchmark which I was not aware of. Well, I made some tests and contrary to my gut feeling, case A is slightly faster or I can say that the difference is neglectable because the difference is within the error margins.

test suites here:

- https://jsbench.me/mqka3oap2y/1
- https://jsperf.com/else-if-or-avoid-with-return/1

using this code

```
for (var i=0; i<10000; i++) {
  test(i)
}
```

Case A: 140,931 ops/s ±1.03%
Case B: 140,147 ops/s ±1.12%

Comment: Those results are within the margin of rounding errors, essentially proving that it doesn't matter one way or the other.